# Is or is not A set determined by its ancestors (elements)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

this [post](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-901-introduction-to-topology-fall-2004/lecture-notes/18901.pdf) says

> Axiom 1a. A set is determined by its elements
>
> Remark 1. It is
>   important to notice that this axiom is a non trivial assertion about
>   belonging. To understand this consider an analogous situation in which
>   we consider human beings in the place of sets and elements, and x ∈ A
>   means x is an ancestor of A. Then clearly A is `not` determined by its
>   ancestors.

I consider ancestors as elements here, which I am not sure I understand it the right way, if yes, "A is `not` determined by its ancestors" seems to be a typo, which should be "A `is` determined by its ancestors", is it?

let A = {'a', 'b', 'c'}

is 'a' an ancestor and an element of set A? I suppose it is.

are 'a', 'b', 'c' ancestors and elements of set A? I suppose they all are.

biologically, this makes definitely sense.

> My sister and I have exactly the same ancestors but we are different
>   people

mathematically, I cannot understand 'a', 'b', 'c' are ancestors of set A while set A is not determined the ancestors {'a', 'b', 'c'}.

Comment: Don't take analogies too seriously.

Comment: Do you have any brothers or sisters?

Comment: "I consider ancestors as elements here"  That is the problem.  THe author wants you to consider ancestors as the parents and parents of a human being.  The author doesn't want you to think of "ancestors" as have anything whatsoever to do with sets.  The author is *NOT* talking about sets at all.  The author is talking about *human beings*.

Answer (score 6):

No, you are *not* determined by your ancestor, since you could have siblings. If I have a brother, then we have exactly the same ancestors.

You are not determined by your children either, since plenty of people in history did not have any children.

---

To your edit:

1. Do not take analogies too seriously. Stick to the definitions instead. Foregoing this idea of ancestors and people and getting back to sets and elements instead.
2. Note that there is no typo. So ancestors ***do not*** determine a person, whereas elements ***do*** determine a set.

Comment: And children typically are shared between two different persons.

Comment: Sure. Also that. But arguably it's not normal that *both* ancestors are the biological father, or the biological mother. Normally that's a way to discern them. I guess I was thinking about that implicitly.

Comment: "Do not take analogies too seriously": To be fair the author is not considering sets to be analogous to people.  The author is considering the *sentences* "A set is determined by its elements", "A thing is determined by the pieces belonging to it" and "A person is determined by his ancestors" to be analogous.  And the author wasn't attempting to show by analogy that the sentences are tautologically true, but actually the exact opposite.  By analogy the sentence is *not* self-evident or tautologically true and can be true in some analogies and false in another.

Comment: @fleablood: The issue is that when one puts too much emphasis on the analogy (here "person" and "ancestors" for "set" and "element"), one tries to fit those familiar terms into the formal context, and that is bound to break. Even worse when one insists to do it opposite to the suggestion of the analogy, but nevertheless, these analogies always break down. So not taking them seriously is  a good advice for life.

Comment: Agreed.  Very, very, very strongly agreed!  (This is why I hate the "sets are bags of groceries and the curly brackets are the bags the groceries are in" analogy.)  Which could be a subtext of the authors point.  In any event though, the author *is* trying to point out the *difference* between sets and people--- not the similarities.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase

> $A$ is determined by its elements

means that if you know all the elements of $A$ you know what the set $A$ is. There can't be two different sets that contain the precisely the same elements.

The phrase

> $A$ is determined by its ancestors

is false. My sister and I have exactly the same ancestors but we are different people.

Comment: Are you and your sister different people, though? I've seen enough Hitchcock to question whether or not a person is also his mother, so surely a person can be his sister too!

Comment: @AsafKaragila I said so, and I don't lie (on stackexchange).

Comment: "I've seen enough Hitchcock to question whether or not a person is also his mother, so surely a person can be his sister too! "  This is a diversion but I think you are confusing  Roman Polanski (Chinatown) with Alfred Hitchcock (everything else).  .... okay... that was very off topic.

Comment: Ooh... you were talking about "Psycho" ("Mother! Oh, God! Mother! Blood! Blood!") and not "Chinatown"  ("She's my sister; she's my daughter; she's my sister; she's my daughter").... Oh never mind.  Way off topic.....

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the entire point.  The point is that a Set is *NOT* a person, and a person's ancestors are *NOT* its elements.

A person is *not* determined by its ancestors.  My sister and I have the exact same ancestors.  But we are *not* the same person.

Now you are arguing that if we called a set a "person" (and if we called a set an "elephant") and if we called the elements of a set its "ancestors" (or "pink go-go dancers") then we *would* say "a person is determined by its ancestor" and "an elephant is determined by its pink go-go dancers".

But that is not what the author is trying to do at all.  The author is trying to point out that the true statement "A set is determined by by its elements" is not as trivial as it sounds.  It sounds trivial.  The elements belong to a set; a set was made by it's elements. And if a set had different elements it would be a different set. So it sounds trivial to say "a set is defined entirely by what elements it has".

But the author is trying to show it is not trivial by showing a case where it wouldn't be true.  Our ancestors belong to us (we all have them); and we are all made by our ancestors (we wouldn't exist without them); and if we had different ancestors we'd be a different person.  But,  as we are individual human beings, it would be false to say "a person is defined entirely by what ancestors she has".